# Como cancelar la llamada al metodo input() en cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el problema siguiente.

En un sistema cliente,servidor cuando un cliente manda un mensaje se anexa a una cola de espera para responder uno a uno los mensjes.

Ahora si el cliente que se esta atendiendo se desconecta debe de leer y reponder el proximo mensaje. El probelema es que cuando el cliente se desconecta el sistema se queda esperando la entrada de texo en el `input` por ejemplo:

```
Recibido: Mensaje de cliente 1
Responder a cliente 1: > Mensaje del cliente2     #Si el cliente 1 se desconecta
```

Lo que se espera es que se salte ese `input` para que no espere la respuesta a un cliente que ya se fue y quede un resultado como esto:

```
Recibido: Mensaje cliente 1
Responder a cliente 1: >        #Cliente 1 se fue
Recibido: Mensaje cliente 2
Respoder a cliente 2: > Mensaje para cliente 2
```

servidor:

```
import socket
import threading

class Hilo1(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,Funcion,Funcion2,cliente,direccion):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.Funcion = Funcion
        self.Funcion2 = Funcion2
        self.Cliente = cliente
        self.Direccion = direccion

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.Funcion(self.Cliente,self.Direccion)
        except ConnectionResetError:
            self.Funcion2(self.Cliente)


class Servidor_C():
    def __init__(self):

        self.ListaUsuarios = []
        self.ListaMensajes = []

        self.Escucha()

    def EliminarUsuario(self,cliente):
        self.ListaUsuarios.remove(cliente)
        for elemento in self.ListaMensajes:
            if elemento[1] == cliente:
                self.ListaMensajes.remove(elemento)
                self.LeerMensaje()

    def LeerMensaje(self):
        while self.ListaMensajes:
            for i,mensaje in enumerate(self.ListaMensajes):
                print("\n",mensaje[0])
                resuesta = input("> ")
                print("\n",mensaje[1],"--","nuevo conexion")
                mensaje[1].sendall(resuesta.encode())
                self.ListaMensajes.remove(self.ListaMensajes[i])


    def RecibirMensaje(self,cliente,direccion):
        while True:
            mensaje = cliente.recv(1024).decode()
            self.ListaMensajes.append([mensaje,cliente,direccion])
            if len(self.ListaMensajes) == 1:
                threading.Thread(target=self.LeerMensaje).start()

    def Escucha(self):
        servidor = socket.socket()
        conexion = ("192.168.8.5",500)

        servidor.bind(conexion)
        servidor.listen(2)

        while True:
            cliente,direccion = servidor.accept()
            self.ListaUsuarios.append(cliente)
            Hilo1(self.RecibirMensaje,self.EliminarUsuario,cliente,direccion).start()

Servidor_C()
```

cliente

```
import socket

conexion = ("192.168.8.5",500)
cliente = socket.socket()
cliente.connect(conexion)

while True:
    linea = input("> ")
    cliente.sendall(linea.encode())
    respuesta = cliente.recv(1024).decode()
    print(respuesta)
cliente.close()
```

Comment: porque no conectas despues del input

Comment: @Durgeoble, conectar que? O adonde

Comment: trasladar ```cliente.connect(conexion)``` justo después del input, si no ingresa nada no se conecta y por tanto no bloquea

Comment: @Durgeoble pero si lo muevo ahi entonces no me daría un error por que cada que trate de mandar un mensaje llamaria de nuevo al mismso socket

Comment: @Durgeoble si muevo esa sección del codigo me sale un error `winerror 10056 se solicito una conexión a un socket ya conectado`

Comment: En caso de que se desconecte el cleinte se podría gatillar un evento asincrono que eleve una excepcion o señal que desbloquee el input en el server.

Comment: @Vichoko, pero que puedes desbloquear el input a eso me refiero

Comment: En teoría, en el servidor debería haber un hilo de ejecución por cliente que se sirve; por lo tanto, bastaría con matar el hilo que corresponde a ese cliente o conexión. En esa arquitectura el rol del servidor consiste en crear hilos cuando lleguen conexiones y cerrarlos cuando corresponda.

Comment: @Vichoko, si de hecho he corregido el script para crear un hilo por cliente y cree una exepcion `ConnectionResetError` cuando un cliente se desconecta pero no fucniona si el servidor esta `>` esperadno responderle al cleinte

Comment: Si el servidor sirve hartos clientes, lo importante es no colocar llamadas bloqueantes en el main loop del server, (es decir, cualquier codigo que espere a que el cliente haga algo), en cambio este deberá ejecutar llamadas meramente asincronas, delegando la tarea de "esperar al usuario" a threads secundarios. El tema es que al parecer pasar excepciones de un thread a otro no es trivial, creo que no es la mejor manera de abordarlo.